# Reading XML files with Petl

Tags: python, python-3.x, petl

I'm trying to parse information from an XML file into a table that has already been created from another CSV file with Petl and am having trouble with the syntax of the `fromxml()` function.

The XML file contains:

```
    <Locations>
  <qld_location>
    <Suburb>Brisbane-Central</Suburb>
    <Lat>-27.46758</Lat>
    <Long>153.027892</Long>
  </qld_location>
  <qld_location>
    <Suburb>Robertson</Suburb>
    <Lat>-27.565733</Lat>
    <Long>153.057213</Long>
  </qld_location>
  <qld_location>
    <Suburb>Logan-Village</Suburb>
    <Lat>-27.767054</Lat>
    <Long>153.116881</Long>
  </qld_location>
</Locations>
```

I currently have a table:

```
import petl as etl

table = (
        etl
            .fromcsv('QLD_Health_Care_Practices.csv')
            .convert('Practice_Name', 'upper')
            .convert('Suburb', str)
            .convert('State', str)
            .convert('Postcode', str)
    )

    +-----------------------------------+--------------------+-------+----------+
    | Practice_Name                     | Suburb             | State | Postcode |
    +===================================+====================+=======+==========+
    | 'BRISBANE CENTRE HEALTH SERVICES' | 'Brisbane-Central' | 'QLD' | '4000'   |
    +-----------------------------------+--------------------+-------+----------+
    | 'ROBERTSON FAMILY PRACTICE'       | 'Robertson'        | 'QLD' | '4109'   |
    +-----------------------------------+--------------------+-------+----------+
    | 'LOGAN VILLAGE CLINIC'            | 'Logan-Village'    | 'QLD' | '4207'   |
    +-----------------------------------+--------------------+-------+----------+
    | 'IPSWICH HEALTH CLINIC'           | 'Ipswich'          | 'QLD' | '4305'   |
    +-----------------------------------+--------------------+-------+----------+
    | 'CATTLE CREEK CLINIC'             | 'Cattle Creek'     | 'QLD' | '4407'   |
    +-----------------------------------+--------------------+-------+----------+
```

and would like to add the Longitude and Latitude in new columns from the XML file.

I am attempting to use the function:

```
table1= (etl.fromxml('QLD_Locations.xml', 'Locations', 'qld_location', 'Suburb', 'Lat', 'Long')
```

but am having troubles understanding the arguments needed for this syntax of XML.

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A "flat" argument list to `.fromxml()` only works if you also have a flat kind of XML structure, where all the data columns have the same name:

```
<ROOT>
  <RECORD>
    <DATA /><DATA /><DATA /><DATA /><DATA />
  </RECORD>
</ROOT>
```

This can be extracted as

```
etl.fromxml('file.xml', 'RECORD', 'DATA')
```

To extract data from a more a complex structure with various column names or nesting, like you have:

```
<ROOT>
  <RECORD>
    <A /><B /><C /><D /><E />
  </RECORD>
</ROOT>
```

Here you must explicitly specify each column you want to extract, using a dict:

```
etl.fromxml('file.xml', 'RECORD', {
    'Column 1': 'A',
    'Column 2': 'B',
    'Column 3': 'C',
    'Column 4': 'D',
    'Column 5': 'E',
})
```

Where 'A', 'B', 'C' and so on are XPath expressions relative to `RECORD`.

Comment: Okay understood, for my instance I only need the two columns Lat and Long as the suburbs are already ordered. The root being `<Locations>` in my file and record being each instance of `<qld_location>` how do I go about pulling the data from each instance into their respective columns?

Comment: I'm sure you can figure this part out on your own. I have not created a "copy and paste" code sample on purpose.

Comment: Am I correct in thinking that `table2=(
etl.fromxml('QLD_Locations.xml', 'qld_locations', {
    'Lat': 'Lat',
    'Long': 'Long',
})
)` should give me the first set of Lat and Long without any errors? I'm quite lost on how to work between the multiple instances of <qld_location>

Comment: The `etl.fromxml()` call already gives you all instances, there is nothing special you need to do for that. What's `'qld_locations'`?

Comment: In your answer,  `<ROOT>
  <RECORD>
    <A /><B /><C /><D /><E />
  </RECORD>
</ROOT>` where I am under the impression that Record is the same as qld_location within my file. I am unsure of how to work between the multiple Record tags that I have.

Comment: Yes, that's the same thing, I was confused because you used the plural `qld_locations`. So yes, if you use `qld_location` then it should extract *all* those instances.

Comment: My mistake, sorry for the confusion. I was thinking too far ahead of myself and couldn't see that I'd already reach the point I needed. Thanks for your help it is much appreciated!

Comment: No worries. :) Realizations one arrives at on their own stick far better than silver-platter solutions, that's why I kept resisting a little.